# Deploy SpringBoot Microservices in Docker

Tags: java, docker, deployment, dockerfile

I have a microService jar and docker file at my windows dextop x folder.
I have installed docker in my windows PC.
I have the below docker.server file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
ADD target/shopfront-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8010
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Now I want to build a docker image from this docker file, then what needs to be done.

I opened the docker terminal and  paste the below command

```
docker build --file=Local location of Dockerfile.server 
//(which is desktop x folder)\
--tag=microserviceName on my wish latest --rm=true
```

.

But it's not working.

As well as I get the current directory and I tried to copy the jar and the docker file in the current docker directory that is not happening.

Please guide what needs to be done.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Please provide the error message you are getting after running the build command

Comment: Please tell how do i build the docker image from the first paragraph. Forget the last pare about not woking.